# Error while Building (compile) wixproj using MSBuild api 15.9.20

Tags: msbuild, wix

I'm using wix in a project and i have a specific need :

Build wixproj using MSBuild from c#.

For that i'm using MSBuild api as folowing :

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string toolsPath = ToolLocationHelper.GetPathToBuildToolsFile("msbuild.exe", ToolLocationHelper.CurrentToolsVersion);
            ProjectCollection projectCollection = new ProjectCollection();
            projectCollection.AddToolset(new Toolset(ToolLocationHelper.CurrentToolsVersion, Path.GetDirectoryName(toolsPath), projectCollection, string.Empty));
            Project project = projectCollection.LoadProject("TestWix.wixproj");
            var result = project.Build(new ConsoleLogger());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

And i get this error :

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\wix2010.targets(1988,5): error MSB4127: The "GenerateCompileWithObjectPath" task could not be instantiated from the assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\WixTasks.dll". Please verify the task assembly has been built using the same version of the Microsoft.Build.Framework assembly as the one installed on your computer and that your host application is not missing a binding redirect for Microsoft.Build.Framework. Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Build.Tasks.GenerateCompileWithObjectPath' to type 'Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask'.

But when i use msbuild command line it's work fine.

Do you have any idea please ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In a rush, can't really answer, but I suspect a bitness problem. 32 vs 64 bit MSBuild. Have seen issues with that before, please try to google. And check [the WiX mailing list](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/). [The different lists](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/mailinglist/). And maybe check the [WiX Bug DB](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues) (generally the open tickets).